# Xmlstarlet using --inplace option in updating xml

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

im trying to update one xml tag using --inplace global option as shown below

```
 xml ed  --inplace -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -u "//x:web-app/x:filter/x:init-param/x:param-value" -v "/cuadmin/showRecovery.do" WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Above is giving me error

```
**I/O warning : failed to load external entity "x=http%3A//java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"**
```

The xml im trying to modify looks like below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>recoveryRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ClassName</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>somename</param-name>
      <param-value>Someurl.do</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
</web-app>
```

Comment: My xmlstarlet version is 1.0.1 . is that the reason im not able to use inplace option ?

Comment: maybe try putting the `-N x=...` first? I think there was some problem with namespace option parsing in earlier versions.

Comment: Without giving the namespace .... xmlstarlet does not do searching correctly

Answer (score 4):

The `--inplace` option was only added in 1.0.2

```
xml ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -u "//x:web-app/x:filter/x:init-param/x:param-value" -v "/cuadmin/showRecovery.do" WEB-INF/web.xml > WEB-INF/tmp-web.xml
mv WEB-INF/tmp-web.xml WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use this thing: `1<>` like this (instead of `>`):

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
  --update "/node/node/@attribute" \
  --value "My new attribute value" "/path/to/xml-file" 1<> "/path/to/xml-file"
```