# XML file structure while editing xml file with shell script

Tags: xml, shell, edit

I am trying to edit a xml file wi9th a shell script. I have found some help like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265833/how-to-update-the-xml-file-using-xmlstarlet). But the Structure of my XML file is little different. This is a example of my XML file:

```
<Code>
  <Type name="abc">this is ABC</Type>
  <Type name="xyz">this is XYZ</Type>
</Code>
```

Here I want to get the `this is ABC` and `this is XYZ` text and then append a String with them like this:

```
<Code>
  <Type name="abc">this is ABC EDITED</Type>
  <Type name="xyz">this is XYZ EDITED</Type>
</Code>
```

I can edit the `'abc'` like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/Code/Type[@name='abc']/@name" -v abc_edited ./abc.xml
```

But How can I edit the `'this is ABC'` String where `'this is ABC'` can be anything unknown?

Comment: if you are ok with `sed`  : `sed -e 's/this is ABC/& EDITED/' -e 's/this is XYZ/& EDITED/'  input.xml`    . However, better not to implement this, go with `xmlstarlet` .

Comment: The String `this is ABC` can be anything. I only know the `name="abc"` . So, can you please tell me how to do this with xmlstarlet?

Comment: I would if I could. Someone else would do.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using awk

Content = (cat abc.xml | awk -f '[{}]' '/Type name="abc"/'{print$3} | sed 's/this is ABC/this is ABC EDITED/i')

Comment: The String `this is ABC` can be anything. I only know the `name="abc"`. So, this isnt possible